# Comment on a method that overrides and is overridden at the same time in C#?

Tags: c#

Here is the scenario

```
     public class Connection
     {
         public virtual void close()
         {
           /*Some code */
         }
     }

    public interface IHttpRelay
    {

         void close();

    }

    public class HttpConnection: Connection,IHttpRelay
    {
         public /*keyword*/ void close()
         {
            base.close();
         }
    }

    public class Http:HttpConnection
    {
         public override void close()
         {
           /*Some code */
         }
    }
```

My question is to know if  i should declare the method **close()** in **HttpConnection** class with an **override** or **virtual** keyword since it overrides and is overridden at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark it with `override`. If you mark it with `virtual` in `HttpConnection`, it will *hide* the base class implementation, not override it. As a result, it could not be used polymorphically. Mark one method virtual, the rest should simply be overrides.

As a simple example

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Frob()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public virtual void Frob()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}

class C : B
{
    public override void Frob()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C");
    }
}
```

Here, B redefines a virtual Frob, it does not override. It follows your example. However, when working with an instance of C through the reference of A, something "unexpected" happens.

```
A obj = new C();
obj.Frob(); // "A" is written to the screen, not "C"
```

What is written to the screen is "A", you did  not get the polymorphic behavior you would expect. When you hide a member instead of override it, you only get the new behavior via the reference of the hiding class. When referenced through a base class, you receive the base behaviors! This is typically not what you desire in a virtual/override polymorphic scenario. If you replace the `virtual` with `override` in class B and then run the above snippet, the output is what you would expect.

Answer (score 2):

The override modifier doesn't prevent the derived classes to override the same method once more. To prevent this your should also use the [sealed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) modifier with it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare it `override` only. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) for `virtual` states:

> You cannot use the `virtual` modifier with the `static`, `abstract`,
>   `private`, or `override` modifiers.

If you think about it, `virtual override` does not make sense: if nothing else you cannot know if *someone* will override your override in the future, and certainly the writer of a class cannot go back and add the `virtual` modifier to a method after you decide to override it.

Comment: Any method you override must already be virtual, so it would be confusing if the language allowed you to add the `virtual` modifier to it once more.